# Streaming Matroska over http

Tags: apache, web, youtube, mkv

I would like to watch my MKV movie collection (encoded mostly using x264 codec) from the browser without converting the format.

Is there any open source alternative to commercial Apache module:

http://h264.code-shop.com/trac/wiki/Mod-H264-Streaming-Apache-Version2

**Update:**

1. It would be great if the app does not require xserver dependencies
2. I would like to have a possibility to create a web app which is similar to youtube. Normally I would use what HTML5 offers me, but the problem is that mkv/x264 is not supported by all browsers.

Comment: You can just use VLC and open file via http:// link. There might be an extension/addon for the browser to use VLC.

Comment: I know I can use VLC, but this app forces me to install xserver dependencies (at least for most Linux distributions), and please correct me if I'm wrong but from my understanding the VLC streaming functionality works like a TV station. A client can't control the stream. It can't reply, go back, go to the certain point. I'm looking rather for something which is more youtube like.

Comment: You will have to do a bit of mix and matching. The best answer (for you) depends on your technical skills.

There is no 100% cross-platform solution as there are no codecs supported in all browsers etc.

The simple and i-want-to-stream-video-now is PLEX.
The little-bit-more-work solution is using any video player and opening the file via http (as suggested by another comment)
The complicated solution is to make streaming output some way (e.g. ffserver) or convert it on the fly some other way (there are solutions out there, but not really easy to find)

Answer (score 1):

bit old but you can do something like `mpv http://server.com/path/to/file.mkv` there is still no support for mkv streaming in the browsers yet, but it would not be that hard to implement as webm is already supported by many browsers and is basicly a more restricted matroska (webm is only AVx/VPx/Vorbis/Opus codecs)

another method is to mount folder over ssh with sshfs or something like that